# Ruby on rails, Validation failed: Countries can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
it "renders index page" do
  projects_user = FactoryGirl.create(:projects_user)
  get :index, id: projects_user.id
  expect(response).to render_template :index
end
```

this is my controller test, when i run it it says:        Validation failed: Countries can't be blank

I am new to stackoverflow and ruby soo any help i get is great

FilesController:

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @pu = ProjectsUser.find(params[:id])
    debugger
    @files = UserFile.includes(:user).where(project_id: @pu.id)
  end

  def new
    @file = UserFile.new
  end

  def create
    @file = UserFile.new(file_params)
    if @file.save
      flash[:success] = "File successfully uploaded!"
      redirect_to files_path
    else
      @files = UserFile.includes(:user).where(user_id: current_user.id)
      render :index
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @file = UserFile.find(params[:file_id])
    if @file.destroy
      flash[:success] = "File successfully deleted!"
      redirect_to files_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "File could not be deleted."
      redirect_to files_path
    end
  end

  protected

  def file_params
    params.require(:user_file).permit(:file, :user_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :project_id)
  end
end
```

Country controller:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  def states
    @states = State.where(country_id: params[:id]).all
    return render :json => {success: true, status: 200, data: @states}
  end
end
```

Country model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :states
  has_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Factory for country:

```
require 'ffaker'

FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :country do
    name {FFaker::AddressUS.country}
  end
end
```

output of error:

```
           ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Countries can't be blank
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib       /factory_girl/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `[]'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:33:in `association'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `block in define_attribute'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /home/nemanja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
 # ./spec/controllers/files_controllers_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

UPDATE:

Factory for project, project has_and_belongs_to_many countries

```
    require 'ffaker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    sponsor_name "John Pare"
    title "Anea"
    start_date Date.new(2016, 5, 7)
    end_date Date.new(2017, 3, 6)
    description {FFaker::Lorem.paragraph}
    number_of_sites_planned "5"
    estimated_enrollment "24"
    feasibility_questionnaire File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/internal_spec_files/app.pdf")
    association :disease_type
    association :disease_condition
    association :user
    association :project_category
    association :project_subcategory
    after(:create) do |m|
       m.countries << build(:country)
    end
 end
```

end

Comment: is there any code that validates the country presence? `validates :country, presence: true` or `validates :country_id, presence: true` if yes then you need to make a instance of country model and assign in to the model that need country

Comment: 1) "Countries" can't be blank? or "Country can't be blank?" 2) You said that when you run the test, you get that validation error message? Then most likely the error stemmed out from a factory creation, probably `FactoryGirl.create(:projects_user)`. 3) Show the stack trace of the error, and show the corresponding code that invoked the error. This would help us inspect the problem.

Comment: icemelt there is validates :countries presnece: true in project.rb model

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the

```
  projects_user = FactoryGirl.create(:projects_user)
```

the creation code (where you defined this factory) does not set a country and this is why you get an error.